# Mystery wooden boards on the ground by my new, old house

Tags: particle-board, ground

We recently bought an old Victorian house in Berkeley, California, and after we moved in I noticed a couple of laminated wooden boards aligned on the floor by the side of the house. I have no idea why they are there, but it seems like someone very deliberately placed them. They're next to the water/gas line, but they are not covering any pipes that I can spot with minimal digging. Any idea what purpose this might be serving?

I removed the board to take this picture, showing that it doesn't seem to cover anything:

[image: I removed the board to take this picture, showing that it doesn't seem to cover anything]

Comment: Weed suppression? Stop some critter from digging there? Could be pretty much anything.  I'd get rid of though - rotting wood laying around the ground by the foundation can attract termites.

Comment: That's my first impression too, but I wanted to make sure I'm not doing something obviously stupid.